# Best ASP.NET MVC Search solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search

https://addons.heroku.com/#search lists some pretty cool search plugins. I'm looking for something like this for my MVC project. I want it to be:

1. Fairly easy to implement
2. Accurate (good results)
3. Great API
4. Doesn't need full text search just searching by title (must like S/O questions)

I'm also wondering if I should just use the Google search API as it seems to be incredible accurate. I'm curious what search system stack overflow.com uses?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for an MVC solution, I will give you one.

Implement interface ISearchable

```
interface ISearchable{
    SearchResult Search(string query);
}
```

Implement class SearchResult

```
public class SearchResult{
    SearchResult(string title, string url, string description, int rank){
        this.Title = title;
        this.Url = url;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Rank = rank;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

Make your ViewModel implement the ISearchable interface.

```
public class MyViewModel : ISearchable{
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    #region ISearchable
    public SearchResult Search(string query){
        string title = "";
        string url = "";
        string description = "";
        int rank = 0;
        // Custom logic to search for an article
        ...
        return new SearchResult(title, url, description, rank);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Register the `ISearchable` ViewModels on `Application_Start`, for example with `Unity`.

Implement `SearchController` and have Action Query.

```
public ActionResult Query(SearchQueryModel model){
   model.Search();
   return View(model);
}
```

In `model.Search()`, do your search through the registered ViewModels that implement `ISearchable` interface, use Whatever Search API that suits you best. Or do NOT use an API.

The reality is, any search will serve you a moment, but when the time comes when it doesn't serve you anymore, you can switch without breaking your implementation.

I know you asked for the "Best ASP.NET MVC Search solution". I cannot pick any particular Product for you since I don't know the internal workings of your solution, your budget etc.

But strictly from ASP.NET MVC perspective, the one that can be plugged into the above scenario, should be a good one. If it fits your bill, etc...